# Difference in declaring strings in C

Tags: c, string, memory-management

How are these two different in C?

```c
char str[] = "xyz";         // statement 1

//and 

char str[4] = "xyz";        // statement 2
```

According to my understanding, the first one assigns a pointer to a string literal while the second one is a character array of 4 characters (including the `NULL` character).

But if this is the case, how are these two stored in the memory?

Comment: They are not. Both are statically allocated character arrays of 4 elements (the fourth of which is the NUL terminator `\0`).

Comment: No. Both cases are equivalent. This one would be different: `char *str = "xyz";` and will fall under your first description.

Comment: Have a look at the difference: https://www.godbolt.org/z/fSh5qR  (the compiled code is identical)

Comment: *the first one assigns a pointer to a string literal* Where did you get that idea?  It's totally false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char str[] = "xyz";
```

declares `str` as a 4-element array of `char` and copies the contents of the string initializer into it:

```
     +---+---+---+---+
str: |'x'|'y'|'z'| 0 |
     +---+---+---+---+
```

In this case, the size of the array is taken from the size of the initializer (3 characters plus string terminator).

```
char str[4] = "xyz";
```

does the exact same thing, except the size is explicitly specified.

In both cases, the contents of `str` are writable - you can modify the characters of the string, like so:

```
str[0] = 'X';
str[1] = 'Y';
...
```

The maximum length of the string is fixed, however - you can only store strings up to 3 characters long (plus the 0 terminator) in `str`.

If you had declared it

```
char *str = "xyz";
```

then `str` would be a *pointer* to the first element of the string *literal*, like so:

```
    +---+      +---+---+---+---+
str:|   | ---> |'x'|'y'|'z'| 0 |
    +---+      +---+---+---+---+
```

All `str` stores is the address of the first character of the string.  In this case, attempting to modify any of the characters in the string leads to *undefined behavior*.  String literals are *supposed* to be immutable, but they are not necessarily stored in read-only memory.  Code like

```
str[0] = 'X';
```

*may* work as expected, or it *may* cause a runtime error, or it *may* do nothing at all.

To be safe, you should declare pointers to string literals as `const char *`:

```
const char *str = "xyz";
```

That way if you write something like

```
str[i] = 'X';
```

the compiler will yell at you for it, so you don't have to wait until runtime to discover the error.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Changed wording from "literal" to "initializer".  Hopefully that's a bit more accurate.